# Chromium Login Help - Version 89.0.4389.82 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Tags: login, chromium

Please help me login

[Profile Login Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQq9o.png)

There appears to be no option to login

I have tried deleting the following files

Login Data, Login Data Journal

I have tried removing and reinstalling Chromium

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320973/chromium-is-deleting-my-linked-profile  -- ie. this is a change announced late-2020 & now implemented by google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sync Chromium with a Google account does not work any more … solutions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322559/sync-chromium-with-a-google-account-does-not-work-any-more-solutions)

Comment: Many thanks, appreciate your help.

Weird that I lost the functionality last year, but that's irrelevant now